# Problems installing custom nodes in ComfyUI using the ComfyUI Manager

Tags: stable-diffusion

I am trying to make my ComfyUI Manager to install some custom nodes. Instead of that I receive message "instalation failed" and the terminal returns me a this text:

```
> Install custom node 'ComfyUI Impact Pack'
install: ['https://github.com/ltdrdata/ComfyUI-Impact-Pack']
Download: git clone 'https://github.com/ltdrdata/ComfyUI-Impact-Pack'
[!] Traceback (most recent call last):
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\ComfyUI-Manager\git_helper.py", line 7, in <module>
[!]     from torchvision.datasets.utils import download_url
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
[!]     from torchvision import _meta_registrations, datasets, io, models, ops, transforms, utils
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[!]     from .convnext import *
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\convnext.py", line 8, in <module>
[!]     from ..ops.misc import Conv2dNormActivation, Permute
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[!]     from ._register_onnx_ops import _register_custom_op
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops\_register_onnx_ops.py", line 5, in <module>
[!]     from torch.onnx import symbolic_opset11 as opset11
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
[!]     from ._internal.exporter import (  # usort:skip. needs to be last to avoid circular import
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\_internal\exporter.py", line 42, in <module>
[!]     from torch.onnx._internal.fx import (
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\_internal\fx\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[!]     from .patcher import ONNXTorchPatcher
[!]   File "C:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\_internal\fx\patcher.py", line 11, in <module>
[!]     import transformers  # type: ignore[import]
[!]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[!]   File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
[!]     from . import dependency_versions_check
[!]   File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\transformers\dependency_versions_check.py", line 16, in <module>
[!]     from .utils.versions import require_version, require_version_core
[!]   File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\transformers\utils\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
[!]     from .hub import (
[!]   File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\transformers\utils\hub.py", line 94, in <module>
[!]     PYTORCH_PRETRAINED_BERT_CACHE = os.getenv("PYTORCH_PRETRAINED_BERT_CACHE", constants.HF_HUB_CACHE)
[!]                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
`[!] AttributeError: module 'huggingface_hub.constants' has no attribute 'HF_HUB_CACHE'
FETCH DATA from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ltdrdata/ComfyUI-Manager/main/custom-node-list.json
> FETCH DATA from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ltdrdata/ComfyUI-Manager/main/extension-node-map.json
```

I would be very grateful if someone can give me a tip what to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't now what worked for me out of these lines, but these lines solve the `AttributeError: module 'huggingface_hub.constants' has no attribute 'HF_HUB_CACHE'` issue:

```
!pip install datasets==2.13
!pip install huggingface_hub==0.16.4
!pip install pyarrow>=8.0.0
!pip install --upgrade pip --user
!pip install --upgrade transformers
```